# Need your help with the integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{e^{\,e^{-x}} \cdot e^{\,e^{x}}}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, closed-form

Is it possible to evaluate this integral in a closed form?
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{e^{\,e^{-x}} \cdot e^{\,e^{x}}}$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is clearly equivalent to
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-2\cosh x}dx=K_0(2).$$
Here $K_0(x)$ denotes [Macdonald function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html), which has integral representation $$K_{\nu}(r)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-r\cosh x}\cosh\nu x\,dx.$$